# Grouping columns and extracting statistics in Python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I'm using the NBA Draft dataframe, which can be obtained [here](https://eimtgit.uoc.edu/prog_datasci_cat/prog_datasci_4/raw/ba658d89bd4e0ae4452ca22b1a077b6a7a2f4bae/data/historical_projections.csv?inline=false) and reading it with pandas.

This is how it looks like:

```
              Player  Position   ID         Draft Year Projected SPM Superstar  Starter Role Player Bust
0   Karl-Anthony Towns  C   karl-anthony-towns  2015    1.030606    0.134767    0.427183    0.163083    0.274967
1   Justise Winslow     SF  justise-winslow     2015    0.875329    0.083529    0.510905    0.176767    0.228800
2   Stanley Johnson     SF  stanley-johnson     2015    0.679493    0.067800    0.423733    0.278500    0.229967
3   Jahlil Okafor       C   jahlil-okafor       2015    0.521661    0.058717    0.409900    0.235533    0.295850
4   D`Angelo Russell    PG  d-angelo-russell    2015    0.511967    0.152033    0.342283    0.096583    0.409100
```

Now what i was trying was to group by the `position` column and get the count of players in each `draft year`. At the same time i wanted to display the median of the `superstar` column.

This is my code so far:

```
data['Median'] = data['Superstar'].median()
data[data['Draft Year']>=2015].groupby('Position').count()
```

But i think this is not yelling what i want. Someone can please point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to groupby both position and draft year

Comment: yeah but how do i get the count and the median in the same sentence? or i have to do it separately? Because when i end it with the `count` method i get a count for all the columns, so i cant get the median

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `groupby` and use `agg`

```
df.groupby(['Position', 'Draft Year']).agg({'Superstar':'median', 'Player':'count'})

                           Superstar    Player
Position    Draft Year      
C            2015           0.096742       2
PG           2015           0.152033       1
SF           2015           0.075664       2
```

or you can create a function

```
def my_agg(x):
    names = {
        'Superstar Median': x['Superstar'].median(),
        'Player Count': x['Player'].count(),
    }

    return pd.Series(names, index=['Superstar Median', 'Player Count'])

df.groupby(['Position', 'Draft Year']).apply(my_agg)

                        Superstar Median    Player Count
Position    Draft Year      
C             2015          0.096742           2.0
PG            2015          0.152033           1.0
SF            2015          0.075664           2.0
```

Comment: Great answer Chris, this is what i was really looking for. Thanks a lot!! :)

Comment: @Miguel2488 there technically may be players with the same name in the same position so you may want to count `ID` and not `Player` as I did in my example.

Comment: No chris it's ok, i wanted to see how many times the players' names were repeated to see if they were playing in different positions or not, and this did the job. Thank you!!